# Cant re-install Google Web Toolkit using Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I installed and updated Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 a few weeks ago. It installed GWT as well as other things. I was able to compile a Google App.  I did several things on Eclipse today and now GWT is gone.  I look at Preference-->Google-->Web Toolkit; the list is empty.  I ran plugin update, it keep saying GWT is already installed and refuse to update/re-install.  I uninstall GWT explicitly and run plugin update; it update without complaint.  But the Preference-->Google-->Web Toolkit; the list is still empty!

How do I force plugin to populate the SDK info in Preference-->Google-->Web Toolkit?
There is actually an "Add" button to configure SDK.  But I dont know the installation directory of GWT.  Where does Eclipse plugin save the GWT?

Seems Eclipse keep track of the installation of GWT SDK in two different place?
My GWT SDK database seems corrupted, and Eclipse plugin seems rely on its own private data base of the status of installation of GWT SDK?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are referring is not the plugin but the SDK.
Download the SDK unzip it then add it preferences->Google->Web Toolkit.
The link to to download the SDK is: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/